# Check if a function returns true for any item in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a function returns true for any item in an array within a function in JavaScript? I'm a mere sapling btw.

No dice unfortunately, maybe I'm not being specific enough... I want any to return true if fun identifies the array to be full and any to return false if the array is empty.

```
    function any(arr, fun){ 
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {  
    if (loop(fun)=== 'false')      //<--- this is what I'm not sure about
    return false;
    if (arr.length>0);
    return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try this: `if (fun(arr[i])=== 'false')` Not sure what `fun` returns, string or boolean!

Comment: I’m not sure what that function actually looks like, but maybe [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) helps.

Comment: Do you want to know if it returns true for **any** element, or for **every** element? Your broken code seems to be checking for every, but the text says any.

Comment: According to your new description, seems like you just want to return a boolean that will be `false` if `arr` is empty and `true` if it has some value in it. In that case you just need `function any (arr) { return arr.length > 0; }`. No extra undefined `fun` function is needed.

Comment: I want to know if it returns true for ANY element

Comment: @JavierConde, your suggestion returns true for any element but doesn't return false for an empty array...

Answer (score 2):

You have a JS array function for that, it is called some. You should use it like this:

```
arr.some(fun);
```

it will return true if fun(x) equals true for any element in arr.

Comment: You mean `every`, not `some`.

Comment: Should be "for **any** element", not "for **each** element".

Comment: @Xufox He gave the correct function for the question, but described it wrong.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake in the description

Comment: `arr.some(fun);` - sounds like something you'd say on talk like a pirate day :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to reduce the elements based on a function returning true or false.

```js
var func = function(item) {
    return item === 'hello';
}
document.write(!!['hello','world','foo','bar'].filter(func).length + '<br>');
document.write(!!['world','foo','bar'].filter(func).length);
```

Comment: Why not just `every`?

Comment: Why not just `filter`?

Comment: Just to clear this up for future answer seekers. `every` returns true or false, `filter` will return a new array with the filtered values. Neither mutates the original array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function and check it's result (not sure what loop is supposed to do but it doesn't seem to help with anything):

```js
function any(arr, fun) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (fun(arr[i]) === false) { //assuming the function returns a boolean
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true; // if we get trough the entire array they must've all been true :)
}
```

You can also use Array.every:

```js
arr.every(function(item) {
  return fun(item); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/rbroden/k5qq4ngy/

```
var arr = [
    false,
    false,
    false,
    true,
    false];

function fun(arrElement){
    return arrElement;
}

function any(array){
    var bool = false;

    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(fun(array[i])) bool = true;
    }

    return bool;
}

alert(any(arr));
```

which basically

- has a placeholder for a boolean to keep track if the condition was ever met
- iterates through the array passed to the function
- if the function ever returns a true, the placeholder bool will be changed to true
- at the end of the function, return the result of the function on bool